# Karate post validation

Tags: karate

I am verifying REST Post request and below is my response. I want to extract value of "id". I am unable to reach to "id". Code "response.body.id" and "response.id", both are not working. They are giving null value or #notpresent

```
<b>ResponseData</b> [
 - <b>StatusCode</b>: 200
 - <b>ReasonPhrase</b>: OK
 - <b>ContentType</b>: application/json
 - <b>Headers</b>: {Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=200], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Server=[Apache]}

 - <b>Body</b>: {
  "id" : "1234",
  "externalContactID" : "7890",
  "_links" : {
  "self" : {
    "href" : "/api/v3/test/cont?Id=hdhd"
```

Comment: sorry this question is not clear. please read this and try and edit it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you extract the value of `id`? also, why there are HTML bold tag?

Comment: @Raptor Yes that's the question . How do I extract value of ID. This response is from third party